# python match only captures first and last group - am I misunderstanding something?

Tags: python, regex, match

I'm working on a little Python script that is supposed to match a series of authors and I'm using the `re`-module for that. I came across something unexpected and I have been able to reduce it to the following very simple example:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "$word1$, $word2$, $word3$, $word4$"
>>> word = r'\$(word\d)\$'
>>> m = re.match(word+'(?:, ' + word + r')*', s)
>>> m.groups()
('word1', 'word4')
```

So I'm defining a 'basic' regexp that matches the main parts of my input, with some recognizable features (in this case I used the `$`-signs) and than I try to match one word plus a possible additional list of words.

I'd have expected that `m.groups()` would've displayed:

```
>>> m.groups()
('word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4')
```

But apparently I'm doing something wrong. I'd like to know why this solution does not work and how to change it, such that I get the result I'm looking for. BTW, this is with Python 2.6.6 on a Linux machine, in case that matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although you're re is matching every `$word#$`, the second capture group is continuously getting replaced by the last item matched.

Let's take a look at the debugger:

```
>>> expr = r"\$(word\d)\$(?:, \$(word\d)\$)*"
>>> c = re.compile(expr, re.DEBUG)
literal 36
subpattern 1
  literal 119
  literal 111
  literal 114
  literal 100
  in
    category category_digit
literal 36
max_repeat 0 65535
  subpattern None
    literal 44
    literal 32
    literal 36
    subpattern 2
      literal 119
      literal 111
      literal 114
      literal 100
      in
        category category_digit
    literal 36
```

As you can see, there are only 2 capture groups: `subpattern 1` and `subpattern 2`. Every time another `$word#$` is found, `subpattern 2` gets overwritten.

As for a potential solution, I would recommend using `re.findall()` instead of `re.match()`:

```
>>> s = "$word1$, $word2$, $word3$, $word4$"
>>> authors = re.findall(r"\$(\w+)\$", s)
>>> authors
['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4']
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation and the additional explanation - the `re.DEBUG` is a new option to me; great to know about!

Comment: @JakobvanBethlehem you should also check out [`re.VERBOSE`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) which lets you split apart your regular expression, add comments, etc and still compile it. Basically, write portions of your RE on each line, add comments with the customary `#` (and make sure to put it in triple quotes). Can make your REs a lot more readable when they are particularly complex.

Answer (score 4):

There are only two capture groups in your regexp. Try `re.findall(word, s)` instead.

Repeated captures are supported by [`regex` module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex).

Comment: For the full-blown case I'm trying to handle, I'm really reluctant to go with `findall` - thanks for suggesting `regex`, maybe that's the way to go

Answer (score 1):

When you have optional or repeated capturing groups, as you do with:

```
(?:, \$(word\d)\$)*
```

The regex only has one place for returning the text captured in that group despite the fact that it matched 3 sections of your string, so it contains the *last* such substring.

To find all the substrings, you can use [`findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) or tokenize the string on some other delimiter.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - although in the full blown case I'm trying to handle I'm trying to prevent using `findall` (it actually matches small bits and pieces I don't want as well, it's the ordering of different other parts of the regexp that makes things work) maybe I can work around it in ways I haven't thought of yet

Comment: Well, another solution is to capture the entire optional part in a capturing group, so you have `\$(word\d)\$((?:, \$word\d\$)*)`. Your regex will then return two groups, the group `1` with the first word, group `2` with the remaining matches, on which you can then run `findall` or `split`. This ensures that the second string at least follows your given pattern.

Comment: Thanks for thinking a bit about this - it is the same direction I was thinking about as well, so I guess I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid regex like this:

```
>>> s = "$word1$, $word2$, $word3$, $word4$"
>>> s.replace('$','').split()
['word1,', 'word2,', 'word3,', 'word4']
```

Using regex you can use `findall()` instead:

```
>>> re.findall(word, s)
['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4']
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question. I'm aware of all the issues you raise - I just can't use them in the full-blown case I'm trying to handle..